# Ubuntu on hybrid GPU laptops

Tags: ati, radeon, hybrid-graphics

I am running Ubuntu on VAIO VPCSE (23FX) that contains hybrid graphics processing capabilities. It is equipped with:

- VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
- VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Caicos [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]

The laptop has a Speed/Stamina selector switch to make changeover between the GPUs.

My queries are:

- How to know which GPU is currently working?
- Whether a Speed/Stamina selector switch is functional in Ubuntu? Making it functional if not.
- What are the good drivers (propriety or open) to install, to get good usability?

Answer (score 1):

I can only try to provide a partial answer to this question as I'm also struggling on this issue.

Here are several links for further info:

- [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&s=0c5e30b19b3489f67897c65c594c1886
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics
- http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide

After going through all these, I couldn't get a satisfactory result from the latest proprietary drivers either from Ubuntu repositories or from AMD website, and I currently use the open source drivers plus a **vgaswitcheroo** script I have slightly modified in order to automatically switch off the power-hungry discreet graphics when the laptop runs  on batteries: http://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com. This script displays **which GPU is currently working** and if they are turned ON or OFF. At least in my case, this only allows me to switch OFF the discreet graphics to save power when running on batteries and cannot make the computer use discreet graphics at all -- commands `echo DIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` and `echo DDIS > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` have no effect.